# Subscribe to newsletter form rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm new to rails and I would like to know how to make a form that submits to a database.  I have tried devise but it seems that it deals with logins/users and it's not working for my purpose.  I don't want anyone to do it for me, I have to learn :).

Comment: You don't need a plugin to submit forms? Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a form that saves to a database is probably on of the most basic tasks to do with rails and is even handled in the "Getting Started"-Chapter in the Rails-Guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Just work on that and you'll get the idea. It looks like it's a lot to do on that page, but it explains also the principles and all that. It becomes really interesting for you in chapter 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a form With Rails 3 is exactly like in Rails 2.